# PHP Excel - extracting data to a variable

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've been working with PHPExcel, and I have been able to take dataset data and create arrays on large data sets. But if I want to allow my client to draw data from a single cell, I can't seem to make this work.

What I'm looking to do exactly is take data from a single cell in excel and place it in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHPExcel as your library.

To get the "raw" cell value:

```
$cellA1Value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
```

or to get the calculated value for a cell containing a formula:

```
$cellB2Value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue()
```

or to get the formatted value for a cell:

```
$cellC3Value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C3')->getFormattedValue()
```